# Is it possible to update a View in RecyclerView without calling a notify method?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar

My app contains a `RecyclerView` with a download `ProgressBar` in each item.  I have a `DownloadManager` class that contains the download progress for each item.  My hope is that I can draw my `RecyclerView` and then the `ProgressBar` can update itself.  I would rather not call `notifyItemChanged()` in every 500ms.

Setting the `ProgressBar` on a `Timer` to update every X seconds blocks the UI thread.  I was thinking maybe my `ViewHolder` could contain a subscriber that subscribes to an Observable in the `DownloadManager` class.  But something about that seems wrong.

Is it even possible to have independent draw functionality inside of `onBindViewHolder`?  Or is the only solution to call `notifyItemChanged` to update a View?

What if I stored my `viewHolder` progressBars in a hash table? Would that work? Everything sounds like a bad idea, help!

Comment: Don’t fight the framework… use notifyItemChanged() which is the correct way to ensure all involved are notified (Adapter, ultimately the view, and the layout engine). Have a Data Interactor (your download manager) notify your presenter (something that has a reference to the View/Layout *and* your Interactor and can deal with the flow of data). I think you’re trying to hack around something that shouldn’t be too complicated in terms of architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. The idea is to pass the `ProgressBar` instance to the `FileDownloader` and update the `ProgressBar` using `onProgressUpdate` function. I had gone through a similar implementation before and hence I am sharing some of my code sample for giving a brief idea of what I had to do.

I had to write a `FileDownloader` class which initiated an `AsyncTask` handling the operation of file downloading. Each item of the `RecyclerView` had a `ProgressBar` associated with it and hence I had to show the progress of each individual file download in the list.

Here's a snapshot of my `FileDownloader` class.

```
public class FileDownloader {

    private String fileUrl;
    private static File f;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressBar mProgressbar;

    public FileDownloader(File file, String fileUrl, Context context, ProgressBar mProgressbar) {
        this.f = file;
        this.fileUrl = fileUrl;
        this.context = context;
        this.mProgressbar = mProgressbar;
        this.mProgressbar.setProgress(0);
        this.mProgressbar.setMax(10000);
        new ImageDownloaderAsyncTask().execute(null, null, null);
    }

    public class ImageDownloaderAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

        protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {

            File dir = new File(DataHelper.DB_PATH);
            if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
            if (f != null && !f.exists()) f.createNewFile();

            try {
                URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                final String contentLengthStr = connection.getHeaderField("content-length");

                InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                String data1 = f.getPath();
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(data1);

                byte data[] = new byte[4096];
                int count;
                int progressCount = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    // allow canceling with back button
                    if (isCancelled()) input.close();

                    stream.write(data, 0, count);
                    progressCount = progressCount + count;

                    int progress = (int) (((progressCount * 1.0f) / Integer.parseInt(contentLengthStr)) * 10000);
                    publishProgress(progress);
                }

                stream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                isDownloadCompleted = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                doInBackground();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return 1;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            mProgressbar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            try {
                mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Tell the calling Activity that file has been downloaded. I had to implement this using a BroadcastReceiver.

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my `RecyclerView`, I had to initialize a new instance of `FileDownloader` inside `onBindViewHolder` like this.

```
// In order to start a download on a button click. 
new FileDownloader(File file, fileUrl, getActivity(), holder.progressBar);
```

My `ViewHolder` had the following implementation.

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    // ... Other elements in the list item
}
```

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your `RecyclerView` once the download is finished by getting a broadcast received in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Hope that helps!